# inApp video streaming for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, macos, http-live-streaming

I am trying to create video streaming for my ipad app.

I've gone through ***HTTP Live Streaming Documentation*** provided by Apple and successfully broke a m4v file into `.ts and .m3u8` playlist using `mediafilesegmenter`.

Now i want to test these files,whether it works or not.

Also they talk about **switching between streams dynamically if the available bandwidth changes**. But they didn't show how to do it.

Please gimme tell me what's the next step shud i take.. i dun't knw how to move further and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out...

i tested these files by hosting them on local server using `XAMMP` and calling the link to `.m3u8` file from my app in `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

In much the same way you'd specify the media URL to a progressively downloaded file with the MPMoviePlayerController object, the same would apply to an adaptive stream.

e.g.

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://www.myserver.com/myfile.m3u8";
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

In regards to your second question: "Also they talk about switching between streams dynamically if the available bandwidth changes. But they didn't show how to do it."

The underlying playback mechanism of iOS + MPMoviePlayerController automatically handles the switching between streams as user bandwidth fluctuates throughout playback. You need not control this behavior manually in your code.